# Do we need to define model everytime we need to train data in LSTM?

Tags: lstm, data-science-model, overfitting

Suppose if I have two datasets where 1st dataset is AAPL stock price and 2nd dataset is GOOGL stock price.

Now if I define the model as

```
model =Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input,n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()
```

and then train and fit it on first dataset

```
    df = pd.read_csv('data\\AAPL.csv', index_col = 0)

    train = df[['close']].iloc[:int(len(df)*0.8)]
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaler.fit(train)
    scaled_train = scaler.transform(train)
     
    #------------------------------------------------------
    generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train,scaled_train,length=n_input, batch_size=1)

    #-----------------------------------------------------
    #fit model
    model.fit(generator,epochs=10)
```

then if I have to fit the model on second dataset do I need to define it again?

if not then why does the output of model.fit differs when I define the model again before fitting it on second dataset?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you trained on AAPL data (model.fit). That means, our weights got adjusted based on the AAPL data i.e.let initial weights are W_init, we got W_aapl now. If you want to train the model from this w_aapl on the googl data, you don't need to intilize the model again. You can use trained model on aapl data. If you need another new model only for googl data, initilize the model and then train for googl data.
If you want to get best model that works on both datasets, get the combined data(aapl+googl) and shuffle data and then train the model.